# magento : add product to shopping cart via API

Tags: cart, php, api, shopping-cart

i want to add product to shopping cart via API , i use this code

```
    //return "Add Product To Cart ... ";
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://mymagent.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 

    $sessionId = $proxy->login('zazaza', '123456'); 

    $cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId);
    //var_dump($result);

    $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $cartId,$sessionId, 10, array(array('product_id' => '166');   


    //var_dump($result);
    return $result;
```

but it return to me

HTTP Error: socket read of headers timed out

can any body help me ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check default_socket_timeout value in php.ini and try to increase it..

Comment: i set it to 6000 but now it return to me HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778511/wsdl-error-http-error-no-data-present-after-http-headers i would suggest to check on google or stack network..